# Handle the response from apex class in to lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I am trying to understand how I can handle response from the Apex Class in to the lightning component Controller. The Apex Class is like below where I am trying to check the Account Id of the Case and show a toast through lightning component

```
public class updateCaseRecord {    
  @AuraEnabled
    public static String passCase(String caseId){
        List<Case> case_recs = [SELECT id,AccountId,Status,Subject from Case WHERE Id = :caseId];
        String returnString;
        for (Case rec : case_recs)
        {
            if (rec.AccountId == '001U000001OgQ0OIAV')
            {
                returnString = 'Assign an actual account to the case.';
            }
        }
        //update case_recs;      
        return returnString;
    }    
}
```

My lightning component is like below

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  controller="updateCaseRecord">
    <aura:attribute name="updateCase" type="Case" default="{'sobjectType':'Case'}"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Pass To CS" onclick="{!c.passCaseToCS}"  />
</aura:component>
```

Lightning Controller

```
({    
   passCaseToCS : function(c, e, h) {
    h.passCaseToCS_helper(c,e,h);
    }      
})
```

Helper

```
passCaseToCS_helper: function(c,e,h) {
    var set_action = c.get("c.passCase");
    set_action.setParams({caseId: c.get('v.recordId')});
    set_action.setCallback(this, result => {
        $A.get("e.force:showToast")
        .setParams({
        type: 'error',
        message: result.returnString,
        mode: 'pester'
    })fire();
    $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
});
$A.enqueueAction(set_action);       
}})
```

But here I am getting error like `Failed to save UpdateCaseCompHelper.js: ESLINT_ERROR: {c:UpdateCaseComp - HELPER} line:col [68:7] --> Parsing error: Unexpected token fire : Source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a period to access the function.

```
}).fire();
```

Comment: Thanks. It did fix the error but I cannot the toast to be displayed am I missing something here

Comment: @user81642 I don't know. Everything appears to be in order. Are you using this component in a Lightning App? If so, you can't use toast notifications, as they only work in Lightning.